# compare to or compared to

Tags: grammaticality

> How does the performance of our method
>   state-of-the-art?
>
> How does the performance of our method compared to the existing
>   state-of-the-art?

May I know which one is grammatical?

Comment: Neither of these sentences is grammatical--they have no lexical verb, only the auxiliary *do*, and *state-of-the-art* can act only as an attributive adjective. I suspect what you want is *How does our method compare to existing state-of-the-art methods?*

Answer (score 1):

Neither I'm afraid. You're lacking some grammar aside from your question.

Try something like this:

> How does the performance of our method compare against existing state-of-the-art methods?

When you're using a verb in an object question (like yours is), you need to use an auxiliary verb, in this case "does". If you use it in present, "does + subject + compare", or if you wish to use it in the past, "did". "How did the performance of our method compare..?"